# Add Tags to Books in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapping, activeadmin, has-many-through

I am using ActiveAdmin gem in my project.

I have 2 models using has_many through association. Essentially, I have a Book model that has_many Tags through a Book_Mapping Table.

**I would like to be able to edit/add tags to a Book from my Book Form in Active Admin.**

But I am having trouble displaying this in my form. Can anyone help me create the proper Active Admin form structure?

**MODELS**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_mappings
  has_many :tags, through: :book_mappings

  ##Not sure if I should use this...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_mappings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

end


class BookMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_mappings
  has_many :books, through: :book_mappings

end
```

**ACTIVEADMIN**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do

###Should this permit any other params? 
permit_params :title

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Book Detail" do
    f.input :title
  end

  f.has_many :book_mappings do |app_f|
    app_f.inputs "Book Tags" do

      ###Other than a Create Tag button, 
      ###The actual form fields don't appear at all...
      app_f.input :book_tag_id
    end
  end
end

#Show Page (Is there a way to show the selected tags here?)
  show do |pic|
    attributes_table do
      row :title

    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should register Book model not CommunityResource I think and please add to permit_params `tag_ids: []`. The form method could look like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Book Detail" do
    f.input :title
  end

  f.inputs "Tags" do
    f.input :tags, as: :check_boxes
  end

  f.actions
end
```

When you want to display the tags on the show page you could do it for example in the sidebar.

```
sidebar 'Tags', only: :show, if: proc { book.tags.any? } do
  table_for book.tags do |t|
    t.column('Name') { |tag| tag.name } # it's depends what you want to display  
  end
end
```

Comment: Any idea how I can then show the tags selected in my View page or Show through activeadmin? I've updated the code above..